# Filtering Windows logs using lambda expressions on non-IEnumerable types

Tags: c#, linq, event-log

I'm trying to get and filter Windows logs based on some criteria, one of which is filter by `Message`. The `Message` property is in `EventLog.GetEventLogs().Entries.Message`. The problem is `Entries` is an `EventLogEntryCollection` and I can't run a lambda expression (*where*) on it. I also tried casting it to an IEnumberable (List) type but it throws an exception and says cannot cast. The other issue is that it's a read-only property which makes it practically impossible to create a new `EventLog` object and add entries to it manually. Initially what I tried was:

```
List<EventLog> filteredList = EventLog.GetEventLogs().Where(
x => string.Equals(x.LogDisplayName, "Some Value")).Where(x => x.Entries.Where(...
```

But obviously `Entries.Where()` won't work because it's not an IEnumberable. I've been thinking about an alternate solution for hours but I'm hopeless now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `GetEventLogs()` returns an array, and `T[]` implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  So yes, this should work.  What compiler error do you get?

Comment: Try with Entries.OfType<EventLogEntry>().Where(....

Comment: I can run `Where` on `GetEventLogs()`, but not on `x.Entries`

Comment: See the extension methods for [EventLogEntryCollection on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrycollection.aspx) -- both `OfType` & `Cast` will get you where you need to be.

Comment: @programmer93 Ah, I missed that detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`EventLogEntryCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlogentrycollection.aspx) (the type of object returned by `x.Entries` in your query) only implements `IEnumerable`, not the generic `IEnumerable<EventLogEntry>`.  To use it with Linq methods you will have to cast each element:

```
x => x.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>().Where(...
```

`Cast<T>()` accepts any `IEnumerable` and returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, where each element is simply casted to the requested type, raising a ClassCastException if this fails.  Since `EventLogEntry` is the only type of object that should be in this collection, this is a safe operation.

(`OfType<T>()` is similar, except it will omit elements that cannot be cast to the requested type rather than raising an exception.  In this particular case, the observable behavior should be identical.)

Comment: Ok that worked, however, I'm not getting desired results (which is probably because I'm thinking about it in a wrong way): Let's say there's an `EventLog` with 500 `EventLogEntries`, and 3 of those entries contain the word `magical word`. When I run the expression I expcet my `filteredList` to have the log with only those 3 elements in the entries, but right now the filteredList is still showing all the 500 entries. Any idea on this?

Comment: What you are asking is "return to me the `EventLog` objects where *any* `EventLogEntry` matches my condition."  If you want just the `EventLogEntry` objects that do, you will have to use `SelectMany()` to collapse the `EventLog` objects down into just a flat sequence of `EventLogEntry` objects and *then* filter those.

Comment: hmm... This is what I tried: 
`List<EventLog> filteredList = EventLog.GetEventLogs().Where(x => x.Entries.OfType<EventLogEntry>().SelectMany(y => y.Source).Where(y => string.Equals(y, "MyValue")).Any()).ToList();`
but it returned an empty list, even though `MyValue` exists in some of the entries.

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  You need to do something like:  `List<EventLogEntry> filteredList = EventLog.GetEventLogs().SelectMany(x => x.Entries.OfType<EventLogEntry>()).Where(...);`

Comment: Well it's taking me back to my starting point :) Now the problem is: How do I put the `List<EventLogEntry` back into its parent `EventLog`? It's a read-only property so I can't just say `logs.Where(condition to find parent).Entries = filteredList;`

Comment: Correct, it is read-only.  You can't wind up with just a list of `EventLog` objects, since you can't change them.  You can correlate the two though:  `var filteredList = EventLog.GetEventLogs().Select(i => new { EventLog = i, Entries = i.SelectMany(x => x.Entries.OfType<EventLogEntry>()).Where(...).ToList() }).Where(i => i.Entries.Count != 0);`

Comment: Compiler says `EventLog does not contain a definition for SelectMany()` on `i.SelectMany(x => x.Entries...)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29327/discussion-between-cdhowie-and-programmer93)